# How to serve a static html file directly from server in React+Express?

Tags: html, reactjs, express, react-router

I downloaded a pretty html page with links to required css and js from a website builder and want to use it as my landing page. I have a full blown React app and want to serve this downloaded html file as my landing page for the / route. What's the best way to go about doing this?

I've looked into `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML>` as in the below example but it leads to the page loading slowly.

````
export default class StaticContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    __html: "" // copy/paste html here
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.state} />
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: why dont you convert your downloaded html as its own component? Or is that dynamic content that changes?

Comment: How is that different from the example I pasted above?

Comment: By doing that you are not relying on `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and React folks have not named it for nothing, may be they are doing bunch of thing under the hood with the value that you provide thus leading to slowness probably. Have you tried by creating a new component though and check the result?

Comment: Found a work around and posted a solution using `http-middleware-proxy`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this by proxying specific paths directly to the server using [`http-proxy-middleware`](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware). See the section titled [Configuring the proxy manually](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development) in the React documentation for more information.

Install `http-proxy-middleware`. Create a file `src/setupProxy.js` in the React client app as follows:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

// Matches landing page at / alone
var landingPageFilter = function (pathname, req) {
    console.log(pathname);
    return pathname.match('^\/$') && req.method === 'GET';
};

module.exports = function (app) {
    // this is for APIs
    app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:3001/' }));
    // this is for the landing page
    app.use(proxy(landingPageFilter, { target: 'http://localhost:3001/' }));
};
```

In my case, I was using Express for my server created using [`express-generator`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html). Handled these routes in `app.js` as seen below:

```
app.use('/api/', indexRouter);

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../public", "landing_page.html"));
});
```

where `landing_page.html` is the downloaded page that we wanted to serve without React

Edit: This only worked in dev. For prod, you'll need to build the React pages and serve them. Follow [this tutorial](https://daveceddia.com/deploy-react-express-app-heroku/) but make sure you have the correct path to build React pages. In the tutorial, it's `client/build`. Might be different depending on your directory structure.